# Using Mbrola voices with pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3, mbrola

I am currently trying to use pyttsx3 on an application.
I have no issue on that but the client would like the application to be delivered with the voices which pyttsx3 doesn't do becauseit use the voices of the os.
Our idea is therefore to use mbrola voices with pyttsx3. The objective is to download the voices and use them in pyttsx3.
Do you know if that is possible.

For the moment, my code looks like that:

```
def main():
    import os
    folder_name="../TTS/Code/Base de test/"
    arr = os.listdir(folder_name)
    for filename in arr:
        langage,sentence=lecture.create_sentence(folder_name+filename)
        test_pyttsx3.speak_sentence(langage,sentence)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score -1):

import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

engine.say("Hello word")

engine.runAndWait()

Comment: Please add context to your answer and format it properly.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would help filter out a specific voice. It's literally just setting it to the first in the list of available voices.